# How to secure Angular2 with Spring Security

Tags: security, angular, spring-security, websocket, basic-authentication

Background: *The site is currently using Spring, Freemarker and Basic authentication. There is a chat window on each URL - On every page reload it got to reconnect the Websockets which is undesirable. Switching over to Angular/SPA will improve this.*

I'm a fan of Basic Auth and new to SPA technologies. Should I continue using basic Auth or switch over to a token based technology such as OAuth2/JWT?

Any input would be very much appreciated :)